# Why does this code break at removeObject:?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
+ (NSString *)numberMatching: (NSString *)number and: (NSString *)secondNumber
{
   NSString *returnNumber;
   if ([number isEqualToString:secondNumber]) {
      returnNumber = number;
   } else {
      NSMutableArray *validNumber = [[self validNumbers] copy];
      [validNumber removeObject:number];
      [validNumber removeObject:secondNumber];
      returnNumber = validNumber[0];
   }
   return returnNumber;
}
```

In case it matters, here is the code for validNumber:

```
+ (NSArray *)validNumbers
{
   static NSArray *validNumbers = nil;
   if (!validNumbers) validNumbers = @[@"one",@"two",@"three"];
   return validNumbers;
}
```

When run, I get the following error:

> -[_*NSArrayI removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed60f00 ... Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[*_NSArrayI removeObject:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed60f00'

That would seem to indicate that removeObject is not a valid method for an NSMutableArray, but it is valid.

Essentially, what I want to do is this: if the two arguments match, I want to return the value. If they don't match, I want to return the third possibility (doesn't match either argument).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `validNumber` is an `NSArray`. You can't remove (or add) objects from an `NSArray`. Use `NSMutableArray` and `mutableCopy` instead:

```
NSMutableArray *validNumber = [[self validNumbers] mutableCopy];
[validNumber removeObject:number];
[validNumber removeObject:secondNumber];
```

Comment: I was specifically trying to make it a mutable array. I thought copy on a nonmutable array returned a mutable array and vice versa. Your solution makes perfect sense, though. I'll try it and check your answer if it works. Edit: that worked, but why can't I accept your answer for 8 minutes?!?!

Comment: Yes, that's how stackoverflow works. Can't accept for 10 minutes to give others a chance to provide a (better) answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you send the `copy` message to an `NSArray`, the copy you get is also an `NSArray` instance and you can't remove objects from an immutable array. In order to get a mutable copy you need to send the `mutableCopy` message:

```
NSMutableArray *validNumber = [[self validNumbers] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Also, calling `copy` on a mutable array gives you a non-mutable copy of the array.